# xcode parse Query button Delete photo and text from the cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform

each cell displays the according comments and photo of the user logged-on. They are loaded with parse.

[image]

Now you want to *Löschen* the button deletes the photo and the comments.

Unfortunately this does not work. Wen I click on the button nothing happens

Unfortunately I understand little of swift and can't get on the solution

The query works, and the app displays the photos and Commons.The query and post code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")

    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (object, error) in

        if let posts = object {
            for post in posts{
                print(posts)

                self.comments.append(post["message"] as! String)
                self.imageFile.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    })

}
```

And here of the "delete"function code that I have tried:

```
    @IBAction func remove(_ sender: Any) {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")

    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (object, error) in

        if let posts = object {
            for post in posts{
                print(posts)

                let objectIdVar = post ["objectId"] as? String
                post.remove(forKey: "objectIdVar")

}

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In remove function:

```
let objectIdVar = post ["objectId"] as? String
post.remove(forKey: "objectIdVar")
```

After removing post from firebase, you need to remove the image and comment from your class array's as well. Like:

```
self.comments.remove(post["message"] as! String)
self.imageFile.remove(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
```

Then reload table view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I this add: self.comments.remove(post["message"] as! String)
self.imageFile.remove(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile) I get the message: Missing argument label 'at:' in call